# Why can't I activate virualenv on Mac?

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv

I'm was working on a project few months earlier that I hadn't modified in the las 3 months. During this period I changed my Macbook and transferred everything with Time Machine. My other projects that don't using virtualenv works fine but in case of this project I am not able to activate the virtualenv.

Structure:

```
coachregiszter
    --bin
    --include
    --lib
    --mcr (this is my project folder where manage.py is)
    --pyenv.cfg
```

If I try: `source bin/acivate` I get this error message:

```
source bin/activate
Script started, output file is started
Script: on: No such file or directory

Script done, output file is started
bin/activate:2: bad pattern: ^[[1m^[[7m%^[[27m^[[1m^[[0m
```

What is the problem?

Comment: take your project in sperate independer folder . Then create virtual env there, activate it and install required package there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't nest the virtual environment within the project—it shouldn't be in version control. Instead, include the requirements file to recreate the environment. Keep the project separate from the virtual environment; environments are disposable, and separating them allows flexibility (like testing on different versions of Django).
Assume your directory is like `Users/coachregiszter/mcr`, your virtualenv can be `Users/coachregiszter/.venv`